# Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=4m10s948ms319µs593ns)

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting below error in my microservcie components and its intermittent

> Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=4m10s948ms319µs593ns)
>
> Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=31m2s68ms83µs32ns).

how to proceed further? where i can check?

Comment: Is this on a local computer which is sleeping? Those are the sleeps. Another option is that the service is massively starved for CPU - likely it's running back to back Full GCs, and the application threads don't get to do any actual work. Add memory or threads. We can't guess anything else without more information. Look up Java application diagnostics, try to use VisualVM or JDK Mission Control to get more insights into the application.